# Double free or corruption when trying to clear memory in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm writing a function that frees an array of pointers, but when I invoke the function, am getting the runtime error 'double free or corruption (fasttop)'. The purpose of the function is to clear out the array, which gets its data from an input file, if the file is already open and the fillArray function is called again.

Here is the function that is causing issues:

```
void freeArray(Country ** g_countryArray)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < g_arrsz; ++i)
    {
        delete [] g_countryArray;
    }
}
```

If it's called anywhere in the program, as far as I can tell, it causes the program to crash. I've run the debugger but am not experienced enough with it to understand the output very much. I can post information from that if it would help.

Comment: Why are you deleting the same pointer multiple times? This makes no sense. One is enough; the second time exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Your problem is `g_arrsz` is `>1`.  That, and your function almost certainly does the wrong thing, as it deletes an array of pointers and not what the pointers point to.  Well actually your problem appears to be you don't know any C++ or C and are using pointers to pointers.  No wait!  Your immediate problem is lack of [mcve].  Basically you got 99 problems, and this question ain't gonna fix them all.

Comment: Thanks for the direction to crafting a better answer. Yes, I am learning C++, so NO I am not an expert. Why do you imply pointers to pointers aren't good? This is for a class assignment, and using a pointer to a pointer is part of the requirement...

Comment: Also, what do you mean by 'it deletes an array of pointers and not what the pointers point to'? Do I need to delete the address of the pointers, not the pointers themselves?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to work with an array of arrays. Most likely You have to first delete all of the inner dimension arrays and then delete the outer dimension array. This is only guessing. To provide a real answer we need a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You left out the `[i]` in your loop body.  You need to drop the `[]` if the individual pointers are to single `Country` objects.

You might *also* want to `delete[]` the overall array; that depends on the rest of your code.

Comment: There is an array of Country objects, which is what I need to delete, so I believe I am accomplishing that now.

Comment: @SethTaylor: Your datatype doesn't correspond to an array of `Country` objects, which would be identified by a single-level `Country*`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `delete [] g_countryArray;` to `delete g_countryArray[i];`.

`delete [] arr` deletes the whole array at once.

Comment: OK so are the two statements 'delete [] g_countryArray' and 'delete g_countryArray[i]' interchangeable in this context?

Comment: No. Not interchangeable. First one : {delete all array elements}; Second one : { delete ith element }. For second one you need to loop thru each element.